# Angular 7 Service returns undefined when has metadata dependency

Tags: angular, angular2-services

When I use inject metadata to working service, it starts to return undefined.

```
import {BasePolicy} from '../base.policy';
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AUTH_USER_TYPE} from '../index';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class BudgetIndexPolicy extends BasePolicy {
  constructor(@Inject(AUTH_USER_TYPE) public userType: string | boolean) {
    super();
  }

  canSeeSaleList(): boolean {
    return this.userType === this.USER_TYPE_1 ||
      this.userType === this.USER_TYPE_3;
  }

  canSeeMaterialList(): boolean {
    return this.userType === this.USER_TYPE_1 ||
      this.userType === this.USER_TYPE_3;
  }

  canSeeExpanseList(): boolean {
    return this.userType === this.USER_TYPE_2 ||
      this.userType === this.USER_TYPE_3;
  }
}
```

I'm able to get service and metada individually  but when I use metada in service, whole service pass to class as undefined. How can I fix it ?